# Eclipse with ADT 21.1 wrong layout preview in editor

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, editor, adt

So I recently updated to `ADT 21.1` via the `Android SDK Manager` from `eclipse`, then I went ahead and updated eclipse as well.

Everything worked just fine, my projects loaded as expected. So far so good I though but then I went into the layouts of my project to do some adjustments and realized that some layouts are acutally displayed wrong in the editor.

To be precise I had a layout with an element that is aligned to the parents bottom and has a bottom margin as well, which works fine on any of my phones, however the editor simply ignores the bottom margin and placed the element right at the bottom.

Here is the layout I am talking about

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
    <!-- titlebar -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_oTitlebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/contact_button_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/contact_button_padding_vertical"
        android:text="@string/contact"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_24"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- logo and title -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/m_oLogo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/contact_logo_dimension"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/contact_logo_dimension"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/m_oTitlebar"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/contact_logo_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/contact_logo_margin_left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_oTitle_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/m_oLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/m_oLogo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/m_oLogo"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/contact_logo_margin_left"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="@string/contact_title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18" />
    <!-- separator -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/m_oContact_Reference_Layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/contact_reference_layout_height"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/m_oLogo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/m_oTitle_0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/m_oLogo"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/contact_reference_layout_margin_top"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_contact"/>
    <!-- content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/m_oContact_Reference_Layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/m_oContact_Image_Send"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/m_oContact_Name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/contact_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20" />
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/m_oContact_Sub"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/contact_sub"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_12"/>
        </LinearLayout>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_oContact_Location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/contact_location"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_14"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_oContact_Phone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/contact_phone"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_oContact_INet"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/contact_homepage"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
     <!-- send button and image overlay --> 
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/m_oContact_Button_Send"
        style="@style/ButtonMain"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/main_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_height"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:onClick="OnClick"/>
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/m_oContact_Image_Send"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/main_button_height"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_height"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/m_oContact_Button_Send"
         android:padding="@dimen/contact_image_padding"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
         android:src="@drawable/send"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also found another one of my layout that seems to have the same issue

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
    <!-- logo and title -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/main_logo_dimension"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_logo_dimension"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_logo_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_logo_margin_top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/m_oMain_Logo"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_logo_margin_left"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/m_oMain_Logo"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/m_oMain_Logo"
         android:text="@string/main_title" 
         android:textColor="@color/zmvo_blue"
         android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
         android:textStyle="bold" 
         android:gravity="bottom|right"/>
    <!-- buttons top left side -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/m_oMain_Logo"
        android:layout_above="@+id/m_oMain_Button_Search"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/m_oMain_Logo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/m_oMain_Title"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_GOZ"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="OnClick"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:tag="@integer/main_tag_goz"
                    android:text="@string/goz"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_GOAE"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="OnClick"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:tag="@integer/main_tag_goae"
                    android:text="@string/goae"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_BEMA"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="OnClick"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:tag="@integer/main_tag_bema"
                    android:text="@string/bema"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_FZ"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="OnClick"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:tag="@integer/main_tag_fz"
                    android:text="@string/fz"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_BEB"
                    style="@style/ButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="OnClick"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:tag="@integer/main_tag_beb"
                    android:text="@string/beb"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_BEL"
                     style="@style/ButtonMain"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:onClick="OnClick"
                     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                     android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
                     android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                     android:tag="@integer/main_tag_fz"
                     android:text="@string/bel"
                     android:textColor="@color/black"
                     android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                     android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- buttons bottom middle -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_Contact"
        android:tag="@integer/main_tag_contact"
        style="@style/ButtonMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/m_oMain_Logo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/m_oMain_Title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
        android:text="@string/contact"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
        android:onClick="OnClick"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Button_Search"
        android:tag="@integer/main_tag_search"
        style="@style/ButtonMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/m_oMain_Button_Contact"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/m_oMain_Button_Contact"
        android:layout_above="@+id/m_oMain_Button_Contact"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_vertical"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
        android:onClick="OnClick"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/m_oMain_Wait_Layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_50"
        android:onClick="OnClick">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/m_oMain_ProgressBar_Layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_50"
        android:onClick="OnClick"
        android:visibility="invisible">     
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/m_oMain_ProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/m_oMain_ProgressBar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_db_init"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So my question is, is this a bug of the editor (since in the previous version it worked just fine and the phones display the correct layout as well) or some kind of layout issue of mine.